# Django, MySQL and regex: not supporting re syntax?

Tags: python, mysql, regex, django

A complicated syntax like:

```
Model.objects.filter(url__iregex=r'^\S+\/\d+\/\S+$')
```

does not work. But something where I leave parts of the string that should be escaped, unescaped does returns elements:

```
Model.objects.filter(url__iregex=r'^http://www.c')
```

What am I doing wrong, or is regex not supported with MySQL in Django?

Comment: If `^\S+\/\d+\/\S+$` is processed with MySQL REGEXP operator, it will not work. You will need something like `^[^[:space:]]+/[0-9]+/[^[:space:]]+$`

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the MySQL REGEXP syntax for the expression:

```
^[^[:space:]]+/[0-9]+/[^[:space:]]+$
```

where

- `^` - start of string
- `[^[:space:]]+` - 1 or more characters other than whitespace
- `/` - a `/` symbol
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `/` - a `/`
- `[^[:space:]]+` - 1 or more characters other than whitespace
- `$` - end of string.

[More details on REGEXP syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)